# Struct com string em C

Tags: c, string, comparação

Eu to com uma duvida tremenda, eu fiz esse algorítimo aqui em C, eu preciso registrar pacientes, nome, idade, sexo, se ele está no grupo de risco, se ele está com covid 19, depois eu preciso contar quantos são do sexo masculino e quantos são do sexo feminino, quantos estão no grupo de risco, quantos estão com covid.

No caso eu to tentando fazer essa comparação com STRLEN ali em "srtlen(citz[x].sexo == 'F') mas não consigo, como eu puderia fazer essa comparação e contar quantos tem de cada sexo?

```html
/*  // strcpy; strcat, strncat
 Name: João 
 Copyright: 
 Author: 
 Date: 17/04/20 20:11
 Description: 
*/
//
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

int function (void);
int main (void){
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE");
 //Declarações
 int idade, sexo, grupoderisco, infectado,qtdm,qtdf, strut;
 //
 printf("\n          Prefeitura de Salvador");
 printf("\n      Primeira capital do brasil\n");
 printf("\n     Secretaria Municipal de Saúde");
 printf("\n   Numeros totais do Corona Virus em Salvador");
 
 strut = function();
 
return 0;
}

int function(void){
int x,z;
int tamanho;
 printf("\n\n\n\n   Registro de dados *(INDIVIDUAIS) \n  ");
 printf("\n\n\n\n   Quantas pessoas infectadas temos na cidade? \n  "); scanf("%d", &z);
 fflush(stdin);

struct Covid
{
 int idade,citz[z];
 char nome[50],sexo[50],grupo[10],infectado[10];
};
 //create
 for (x=0;x<z;x++){
 struct Covid citz[x];
 printf("Instruções gerais: Para o programa funcionar, deve-se escrever o nome completo, sexo com 'M' ou 'F', grupo de risco e se está infectado com 'S' ou 'N'' \n");
 printf("Nome completo = \n");
 fgets(citz[x].nome, 50, stdin);
 printf("Sexo = \n");
 fgets(citz[x].sexo, 50, stdin);
 printf("Encontra-se no grupo de risco = \n");
 fgets(citz[x].grupo, 10, stdin);
 printf("Está infectado pelo (COVID-19)? = \n");
 fgets(citz[x].infectado, 10, stdin);
 printf("Qual sua idade? = \n");
 scanf("%d", &citz[x].idade);
 fflush(stdin);
 
 tamanho = strlen(citz[x].sexo == "F");
 printf("Sexo = ", tamanho);



}// final do looping da struct citz[x]
 
 //system("cls");
 //Área de parametros de controle
 printf("[Estatisticas]\n\n\n\n");
 printf("Um total de pessoas infectadas [%d]", z);

  
  
  
  
  
  return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Note que você declara sua variável `z` e a utiliza sem ter feito qualquer atribuição a ela. Além disso você utiliza `citz`como parte integrante da struct Covid e também como o nome de um array de struct Covid.

Comment: Eu declarei ela ali na função Function e depois inicializei ali no scanf logo abaixo, é isso q vc quis dizer?

Comment: O scanf foi cortado na minha tela. Agora eu vi, está OK. Verifique a utilização do nome de variável citz.

Comment: Eu troquei agora, o struct Covid citz[x] para struct Covid citz[z]; e o for que estava em cima coloquei em baixo do struct

Answer (score 1):

strlen() é para medir o comprimento da string. Para comparar, você deve usar alguma função da família strcmp, como por exemplo

```
strcmp(sexo, "F") == 0
```

strcmp() retorna -1, 0, ou +1 conforme a string é menor, igual ou maior (lexicograficamente falando) que o modelo. No caso, para testar igualdade, teste se ela retorna zero.

Outra opção, se você tem certeza que a string sempre tem apenas 1 caractere, é comparar apenas o caractere:

```
*sexo == 'F'
```